# Jquery Datatable: Unable to add new column based on result of ajax call - Getting error datatable requested unknown parameter

Tags: jquery, datatables, html-table

I am new to datatables (http://datatables.net/). I have a requirement of adding column based on the computation from result of my ajax call. I tried below approach but get error " datatable Requested unknown parameter  from the data source for row" . Is this the right approach for this kind of requirement. I'll really appreciate your help in this regard.
This is how table structure looks:

```
<table id="result" class="show_hide">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Time1</th>
            <th>Time2</th>
            <th>Elapsed Time</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is sample output from my ajax call:

```
[{
    "time1": 12345,
    "time2": 56789
},  
{
        "time1": 2000,
        "time2": 3000
}]
```

This is what I am trying with datatables

```
$('#result').dataTable({
        "sAjaxSource": "http://" + hostname + ":" + port + api,
        "sAjaxDataProp": "",
        "iDisplayLength": 25,
        "bRetrieve": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "aoColumns": [{
            "mDataProp": "time1"
        },
        {
            "mDataProp": "time2"
        },
       {
            "mRender": function(data, type, row) {

                return (row.time2 - row.time1);
            },
            "mDataProp": null
       }
    ]
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think we need any extra property in return object....I figured out the problem. I was using jquery datatable 1.9.0 but this feature of mRender works with 1.9.4. Upgraded the js and this code works like charm with 1.9.4.

Comment: We have 1.9.4, but still the problem remains. Do we have to do any other thing?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [documentation](http://datatables.net/usage/server-side) from the server you must return an object with some required properties.

So you should return something like

```
{ iTotalRecords : 2, iTotalDisplayRecords: 2, aaData: [{
    "time1": 12345,
    "time2": 56789
},  
{
        "time1": 2000,
        "time2": 3000
}] 
}
```